# Htaccess redirections in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to perform the following permanent redirections in .htaccess file, but I can not make them work. Can you help me?

Thank you very much. Regards!

Redirects are these:

```
http://www.mapfre.com.pa/productos/#39 to https://www.mapfre.com.pa/seguros-pa/seguros/seguros-salud/

http://www.mapfre.com.pa/productos#36 to https://www.mapfre.com.pa/seguros-pa/seguros/seguros-auto/

http://www.mapfre.com.pa/?post_type=corporativo&p=21 to https://www.mapfre.com.pa/seguros-pa/sobre-mapfre-panama/historia/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to make server-side redirect for URLs with an anchor `#`.

The last one may be done by this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post_type=corporativo&p=21$
RewriteRule ^$ /seguros-pa/sobre-mapfre-panama/historia/ [R=301,L]
```